# "context.auth.uid" TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm just trying to fetch "**uid**" of my authenticated users using firebase functions. But every time I run the function in "**firebase functions:shell**". I get these errors. can anyone help me fix this problem?

"context.auth.uid" **TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined**

[image]

```
exports.sendNewUser = functions.database.ref('/Users/')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    const userId = await context.auth.uid;

    const tokenPath = await admin.database().ref('Notify').once('value')

    var message = []

    tokenPath.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        var allTokens = childSnapshot.val().expo

        if (allTokens) {
            message.push({
                "to": allTokens,
                "header": " Users",
                "body": "New user has been added, check them out!!!"
            })
        }
    })

    await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(message)
    })

    console.log("The user ID is : " + userId)

})
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "firebase-admin": "6.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you share the version of Firebase Functions you are using? You will find it in the package.json file.

Comment: Yeah!! I just added it :)

Comment: Ok, your version seems fine, i.e. it's in line with your parameters. Other question: do you use the auth option to run your function as a particular end user, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_realtime_database_functions

Comment: Also, note that if I am not mistaking you should not do `const userId = await context.auth.uid;` but just `const userId = context.auth.uid;`

Comment: yeah, I have gone through the docs!!! auth needs to be added to the function, Will it fetch a particular logged in users `uid` once I deploy it to cloud ?!

Comment: Yes, you can mock an end user with `myDatabaseFunction('data', {auth: {uid: 'abcd'}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [running Realtime Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_realtime_database_functions) is clear:

> By default, the shell runs Realtime Database functions with
>   administrative privileges. Use the auth option to instead run
>   functions as a particular end user, or as an unauthenticated user:
>
> ```
> # to mock unauthenticated user
> myDatabaseFunction('data', {authMode: 'USER'})
> # to mock end user
> myDatabaseFunction('data', {auth: {uid: 'abcd'}})
> ```

You need to pass the last object that simulates the auth payload in the context.  Without that, auth will contain nothing.

It will work fine when you publish it.

You don't need to use `await` when accessing the uid.  It's not an asynchronous function.

Comment: Yeah I tried it :) Now everything's working fine I'm receiving notifications while running the functions locally but after deploying even after creating new data the function is not triggered and the logs are also not showing up:(

Answer (score 3):

The context.auth.uid will be undefined with the onCreate trigger, as this is triggered by the cloud funtions runtime and not the user that created the document.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64345666/4868790