# Unable to retrieve the user ID from the context

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have the following Google cloud function:

```js
export const doSomething = functions
  .https.onCall(async (data: any, context: functions.https.CallableContext) => {
    const userID = context.auth.uid
    if (!userID) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'unauthenticated',
        'Unable to retrieve the user ID from the context.'
      )
    }
    ...
  })
```

8 or 9 out 10 requests, `userID` will be valid. But once in a while, if will be `undefined`.

A reduced version of `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
      ...
     },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/functions-types": "^0.5.0",
    "@firecode/admin": "^0.13.0",
    "@google-cloud/opentelemetry-cloud-trace-exporter": "^2.1.0",
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^3.4.1",
    "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "^4.2.0",
    "@google-cloud/tasks": "^3.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.7.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.0",
    "luxon": "^2.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "semver": "^7.3.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Any idea why `context.auth.uid` can sometimes be invalid? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["context.auth.uid" TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680752/context-auth-uid-typeerror-cannot-read-property-uid-of-undefined)

Comment: No, not really. Like I said, 80% of the time works great, but not always. I don't see anything out of the ordinary after reading the post you mention. But thanks for the reference.

Comment: The most sensible explanation would be that the caller really doesn't have a current user at the time it calls your function. How have you ruled that out?

Comment: Good question. It’s an iOS app using the Firebase SDK. The context AFAIK is managed entirely by Firebase. If the user is not passed along the context by Firebase, I’m assuming this has something to do with the JWT perhaps expiring. But this a question for Firebase engineers: if the token expires, does the function get called anyway? And if so, is it best practice to return an error to the client to try to refresh the token? How would I know where the issue lies?